# I am working on Asp.net MVC application and want to use wmd editor. .

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to include wmd editor in my application. I tried many times but final result is in this picture.

[image]
Problem is that buttons are not visible. 
Any solution??

Answer (score 0):

My guess is they are not loading, most likely a result of a 404 error not finding the images to populate that area. I would suggest downloading a tool such as fiddler and running it just before you run your program. This program will list out all the 404 errors and then its just a matter of making sure the image is where it needs to be. Good luck.